# AWS API Gateway : How to store certain headers to cache and extract and inject into the following requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, caching, http-headers, aws-api-gateway

In a request to the API gateway after user authentication, I want to extract certain headers from the authorization header and store them in the local cache and retrieve in the following requests to inject into the request to be routed to the backend. I don't want to expose these headers and other sensitive information to the client.

Can this be done in the request/response mapping template?

How to set the TTL for those cached headers?

If the cache is not present or expired, is it possible to redirect the request to authentication and continue the same flow?

Comment: *"store them in the local cache"*  What is the "local cache?" Local to where?  *"I don't want to expose these headers and other sensitive information to the client."* It's unclear what this means.  The `Authorization` header has already been "exposed" to the client, because the client is typically the source of that header.  To address this question properly, I think we need some very concrete examples of what comes from where and how it is used... or, really, a full description of what you are actually trying to accomplish (and not just how you are envisioning you might implement it).

Comment: Currently we are using CA layer 7 API gateway, It supports features Store Cache and Lookup Cache assertion for caching OAuth Token required to invoke a target API. We save the extracted headers in cache,  I am trying to achieve the same in AWS API gateway. 
Also, we are are authenticating the user and sharing the SessionID instead token, Token is saved in cache and validated with the sessionID from the request. I don't know the advantage of doing this, but this is the way it's implemented. I am new to these concepts, It would be great if you can share best practices of implementing in new one